# Mounting windows partition from live ubuntu

Tags: mount, windows, live-usb

I just mended an old laptop, that have a dual boot windows8/linux

I can't remember any password, I decided to use a live ubuntu to hack into windows. Problem is I can't mount windows partition in write mode :

```
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.)
```

I tried to fix this problem using `ntfsfix`

```
$ sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdb2
Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

It failed as well, I tried adding `-o remove_hiberfile` when mounting without success either.

How can I boot windows partition in write mode ?

Comment: Why just don't reset Windows password via a bootable flashdrive/CD with password reset tool?

Comment: @Xaqron : where can I find an iso for that ?

Comment: is Ophcrack a valid option ?

Comment: What is the Windows version? No `Ophcrack` tries to crack the password which you don't need to waste time over.

Comment: @Yaron, I've seen this question, it doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try booting up windows and on the log-in screen press "Shut-Down" button. If the fast-booting is on this won't work.(I know this isn't the answer just a small thing you might have forgot, i would've posted this as a comment but i don't have the enough reputation).

Comment: Yes, I did try to boot windows, I even tried many password combination I might have used in the past.

Comment: Wait, i remember last time i accessed the files from the hibernated windows, i actually mounted it BUT i can't change them, i managed to open them in read only mode. I am 100% sure that i did it. There is a solution i will try to find the commands i used back then...There is a solution, try digging you might find it.